# Painfully Slow Development Page Loads With Cacheing Enabled Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, development-environment

I've developed low level (model) caching for my app using the [Dali gem](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).

I turned on caching in development by modifying `environemnts/development.rb`:

```
#Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  #config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

#caching
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

My low level cacheing works great, but now pages take on the order of several seconds to render:

```
Started GET "/locations/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-20 08:30:08 -0500
Processing by LocationsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
 (1938.6ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='locations'
Location Load (157.8ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "15"]]
 (1.6ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='users'
User Load (26.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.1ms)  COMMIT
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-09-19 14:18:08.387095', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-09-20 13:30:11.455989', "sign_in_count" = 42, "updated_at" = '2013-09-20 13:30:11.457132' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
 (1.0ms)  COMMIT
 (1.6ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='roles'
 (1.7ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='users_roles'
 (44.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "15"]]
 (30.8ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='zones'
Zone Load (60.8ms)  SELECT "zones".* FROM "zones" WHERE "zones"."location_id" = 15
 (24.8ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='zone_geometries'
ZoneGeometry Load (15.1ms)  SELECT "zone_geometries".* FROM "zone_geometries" WHERE "zone_geometries"."zone_id" IN (450, 451, 457, 455, 456, 468, 463, 453, 470, 452, 454, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 464, 465, 466, 467, 469, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 489)
 (42.3ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='geometries'
Geometry Load (65.9ms)  SELECT "geometries".* FROM "geometries" WHERE "geometries"."id" IN (314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 346, 342, 343, 344, 345, 366, 352, 353, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 368, 334, 340, 341, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 367, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 385)
Rendered locations/show.html.haml within layouts/locations (31.1ms)

Compiled locations.js  (1072ms)  (pid 6750)
Compiled application.js  (152ms)  (pid 6750)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (8.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9407ms (Views: 5669.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3018.3ms)
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.slider.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.base.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.all.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/open_layers/style.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/pagination.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/a_maps_layout.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/factory_details.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/home.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/workers.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/tags.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/companies.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/locations.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/tracked_points.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/alerts.css?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/openlayers/OpenLayers.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/openlayers-rails.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/unity/UnityObject2.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.button.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.mouse.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.draggable.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.droppable.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-clip.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-drop.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fold.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-scale.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-shake.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-slide.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.slider.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.sortable.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.ui.all.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/index.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/excanvas.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/plugins/pieRenderer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/plugins/barRenderer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/plugins/categoryAxisRenderer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/plugins/canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/jqplot/plugins/canvasTextRenderer.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/companies.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/alerts.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/factories.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/home.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/hr_dept.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/location_import.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/locations.js?body=1
Cache write: e4ea0e53c7d1e141e39a45c019ddb9c80b6db6f3
Cache read: e4ea0e53c7d1e141e39a45c019ddb9c80b6db6f3
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/locations.js?body=1
Cache write: http://localhost:3000/assets/locations.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/tags.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/tracked_points.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/workers.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/zones.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1
Cache write: db64b7bbc4b0bc22a81f6e07dbabfe5ce1fea54b
Cache read: db64b7bbc4b0bc22a81f6e07dbabfe5ce1fea54b
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1
Cache write: http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/private_pub.js?body=1
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/zoom-in.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/zoom-out.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/pan.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/rotate.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/reset-view.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/view-2D.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/Tulsa_Driller.JPG?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/openlayers/theme/default/style.css?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/openlayers/img/layer-switcher-maximize.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/assets/openlayers/img/layer-switcher-minimize.png?
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/locations/15/alerts?cache=1379683824151
```

It almost looks as if the page is being precompiled before every visit in an illfated attempt to use cacheing at a higher level.  In production the pages are zippy and quick.

It takes 3 seconds for ActiveRecord to run on this page but 6 seconds for the views?

```
Completed 200 OK in 9407ms (Views: 5669.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3018.3ms)
```

Are there some other settings I need to enable in order to use cacheing in development without killing my page load times?

- Rails 3.2.13
- ruby 1.9.3-p392